# The function to validate my forms is not getting called

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a problem with my form. It submits successfully, and everything seems to be fine until the moment of submission. I have a function called **isValidForms** that collects all the mandatory fields and checks if they are empty. In that case, it displays an error and also shows an alert indicating which fields are not filled. This is how it should work.
However, when I press the submit button (which should normally be disabled if any field is not filled), it submits the form immediately without any errors.

I have tried to debug the code, but it's as if it doesn't enter the function at all. I have been checking if it could be a syntax or indentation issue, but honestly, I don't understand what the problem is.

If someone could lend me a hand, it would be greatly appreciated.

Short example of form :

```js
// Fonction permettant d'afficher un message d'erreur
function showError(inputId, errorMsg) {
    var errorElement = document.getElementById(inputId + 'ErrorMsg');
    errorElement.textContent = errorMsg;
    errorElement.style.display = 'block';
}

// Fonction permettant d'effacer le message d'erreur
function clearError(inputId) {
    var errorElement = document.getElementById(inputId + 'ErrorMsg');
    errorElement.style.display = 'none';
}
function isValidForms() {
    let isValid = true;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

    // Obtenir les valeurs des champs de saisie obligatoires
    var name = document.forms["FormAccident"]["name"].value;
    var surname = document.forms["FormAccident"]["surname"].value;

    // Validation des champs obligatoires
    if (name.trim() === '') {
        showError('name', 'Veuillez remplir le champ "Nom"');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        clearError('name');
        console.log("test1");
    }

    if (surname.trim() === '') {
        showError('surname', 'Veuillez remplir le champ "Prénom"');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        clearError('surname');
    }


    if (!isValid) {
        submitButton.disabled = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        submitButton.disabled = false;
        console.log("test3");
    }

    if(isValid === false){
        alert("Le formulaire comporte une erreur ou est incomplet pour les champs suivants : \n" +
            (name ? "" : "\nPrenom")            +
            (surname ? "" : "\nNom"));          
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form action="send_email.php" id="FormAccident" method="post" name="FormAccident" onsubmit="return isValidForms()">

        <input name="formAccident" type="hidden" value="true"/>

        <div class="container mt-5 border-bottom border-dark">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Données personnelles</h4>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nom*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nom" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2 errorColor" hidden id="nameErrorMsg">Format invalide</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Prénom*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Prénom" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2 errorColor" hidden id="surnameErrorMsg">Format invalide</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container mt-5">
                    class="g-recaptcha"
                    data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxx"
                    data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn">
            </div>
            <div class=" container form-group row mt-5 mb-5">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" form="FormAccident" type="submit" value="ENVOYER" id="submitBtn">ENVOYER</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>   
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The code shown appears to be working as expected for me.  Can you clarify exactly how you're observing the problem?

Comment: why not just use the form validation system by adding required attributes? Otherwise, simply deactivating a submit button does not prevent form submission.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Setting breakpoints in your browser's developer console is not that hard

Comment: hey @David I encounter this issue while testing the form. I fill in some of the mandatory fields but not all (that's when the errors and the alert should appear). However, none of these mentioned issues appear, and the form is submitted directly even when the mandatory fields are empty.

Comment: If you disable the submit button, clicking it won't call isValidForms any more, so how will you re-enable the submit button?

Answer (score 0):

You had an issue with your html, I've also made some minor changes.

all should work correctly now, also please verify that your `form`'s `action` points to a legitimate page/link, also ensure that you are using the correct `form`'s `method` such as `GET` or `POST`

```js
// Fonction permettant d'afficher un message d'erreur
function showError(inputId, errorMsg) {
    var errorElement = document.getElementById(inputId + 'ErrorMsg');
    errorElement.textContent = errorMsg;
    errorElement.style.display = 'block';
}

// Fonction permettant d'effacer le message d'erreur
function clearError(inputId) {
    var errorElement = document.getElementById(inputId + 'ErrorMsg');
    errorElement.style.display = 'none';
}

function clearX(){
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
        submitButton.disabled = false;
}
function isValidForms() {
    let isValid = true;
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitBtn');

    // Obtenir les valeurs des champs de saisie obligatoires
    var name = document.forms["FormAccident"]["name"].value;
    var surname = document.forms["FormAccident"]["surname"].value;

    // Validation des champs obligatoires
    if (name.trim() === '') {
        showError('name', 'Veuillez remplir le champ "Nom"');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        clearError('name');
        console.log("test1");
    }

    if (surname.trim() === '') {
        showError('surname', 'Veuillez remplir le champ "Prénom"');
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        clearError('surname');
    }


    if (!isValid) {
        submitButton.disabled = true;
        return false;
    } else {
        submitButton.disabled = false;
        console.log("test3");
    }

    if(isValid === false){
        alert("Le formulaire comporte une erreur ou est incomplet pour les champs suivants : \n" +
            (name ? "" : "\nPrenom")            +
            (surname ? "" : "\nNom"));          
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form action="send_email.php" id="FormAccident" method="post" name="FormAccident" onsubmit="return isValidForms()">

        <input name="formAccident" type="hidden" value="true"/>

        <div class="container mt-5 border-bottom border-dark">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase mb-4">Données personnelles</h4>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nom*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input onkeydown="clearX()" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Nom" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2 errorColor" hidden id="nameErrorMsg">Format invalide</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Prénom*</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <input onkeydown="clearX()" class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Prénom" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-2 errorColor" hidden id="surnameErrorMsg">Format invalide</div>
            </div>
            <div class="container mt-5 g-recaptcha"
                    data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxx"
                    data-callback="YourOnSubmitFn">
            </div>
            <div class=" container form-group row mt-5 mb-5">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <button class="btn-lg btn-primary" form="FormAccident" type="submit" value="ENVOYER" id="submitBtn">ENVOYER</button>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>   
    </form>
</div>
```